# OrientDB function error when accessing query result

Tags: javascript, orientdb

I have the following function in OrientDB studio, the functions saved with no problem:

```
var entities= db.query("select Name from F__Entity_Master");

getTemplate(0);

function getTemplate(index){
  if (index >= entities.length){
    return entities;
  } else {
      var sql = "select from F__Subjects where subjectCode='"+ entities[index]['@class']+"'";
      var template = db.query(sql);
      entities[index]['template']= template;
      index += 1;
      getTemplate(index);
  }

}
```

Running the function in studio generates the following error:

> Erroronparsingscriptatposition#0: ErroronexecutionofthescriptScript: GetEntities------^sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorException: Javaclass"com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument"hasnopublicinstancefieldormethodnamed"template".(#12)inatlinenumber12Javaclass"com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument"hasnopublicinstancefieldormethodnamed"template".(#12)

I used recursion to avoid using null values before fetching data from database. Using for loop generates similar error.

There are no relations between F__Subjects and F__Entity_Master as for every F__Subjects record a relevant class named with subjectCode field of F__Subjects record is generated and inherited from the F__Entity_Master. So the only way to detect relation is to use the subjectCode field to get the class meta information from he F__Subjects class.

Any ideas?

**Solved**
I used Lvca hint and here is the correct version of the function after few trials:

```
var entities= db.query("select from F__Entity_Master");

getTemplate(0);

return entities


function getTemplate(i){
 if (i >= entities.length){
    return ;
  } else {
      var sql = "select from F__Subjects where subjectCode='"+ entities[i].getClassName()+"'";
      var template = db.query(sql);
      entities[i].field('template', template[0].toMap());
      i += 1;
      getTemplate(i);
  }


 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

entities is an array of ODocument, so to get/set a field you should use respectively the `field(name)` and `field(name,value)` methods.

Comment: As Lvca said, the result was not an array of JSONs but an array of java ODocument object, you can find more details of this object in: [link](http://www.orientechnologies.com/javadoc/latest/com/orientechnologies/orient/core/record/impl/ODocument.html#load-java.lang.String-)

Comment: @Lvca: Does accessing fields in query results with field(name) work in javascript functions for OrientDB 2.x ? I can't get it to work. I get null values instead.

Answer (score 0):

try `field.getProperty()`

this worked for me when writing functions in javascript for the orientdb server